# Sortby function combined with Unique and filter functions: how to use it correclty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table in excel, namely "table1":

| CHECK | City | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | New York | USA |
| Yes | Barcelona | Spain |
| No | Rome | Italy |

The field "Check" is dynamically calculated with a formula

So far, I am using the following formula in another sheet to show only the Check= "Yes" rows:

=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1;Table1[CHECK]="YES";""));3;1)

How can I sort by Country first, and then by the city in alphabetical order?

I tried the following but I get an erorr:

=SORTBY(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1;Table1[CHECK]="YES";""));Table1[Country];1;Table1[City];1)

Any suggestion? It should be easy but I am struggling to figure out how to fix it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conceptual problem is that the array argument for the `SORTBY` function is not the original table; rather it is the array returned by the `FILTER` function.

One method of using `SORTBY` for this issue would be:
*Be sure to replace the comma argument separators with semi-colon for your locale*

Note that we need to use the `INDEX` function to return the appropriate columns for `SORTBY` function.

```
=LET(x, FILTER(TableX,TableX[CHECK]="Yes"),
          SORTBY(x,INDEX(x,0,3),1,INDEX(x,0,2),1))
```

[image]

***Edit:***
If you don't have the `LET` function, you can just use the equivalent:

```
=SORTBY(FILTER(TableX,TableX[CHECK]="Yes"),
INDEX(FILTER(TableX,TableX[CHECK]="Yes"),0,3),1,
INDEX(FILTER(TableX,TableX[CHECK]="Yes"),0,2),1)
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you so much for clarifying the issue. Just wondering, can I achieve the same outcome without the let function that for some reason is not available in my version of MS Excel?

Comment: @Stefano Sure, just replace `x` with the formula that it represents `FILTER(TableX,TableX[CHECK]="Yes")`.   You'll have to do that three times.

Comment: Isn't this avoidable by sorting first and then filter?

Comment: @P.b I think you'd have a similar problem, but with the FILTER function.

Comment: A very good solution together with good explanation, which consumed much of my time before!